# React-router back browser button doesn't refresh page on first click

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am facing an issue with react-router, when I am on Home page (`/`), and I click to Log In page button (`/login`), I have the login page displayed, normal... and then I click on browser back button, nothing happen, it doesn't go to Home page, but the URL in the browser is the Home page one (`/`). Then I click on the forward button in the browser, and I get finally the home page but with the URL of the login page (/login).

Here is the code:

In index.js

```
// Create browser history to use in the Redux store
const baseUrl = document.getElementsByTagName('base')[0].getAttribute('href');
const history = createBrowserHistory({ basename: baseUrl });

// Get the application-wide store instance, prepopulating with state from the server where available.
const initialState = window.initialReduxState;
const store = configureStore(history, initialState);

const rootElement = document.getElementById('root');

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
      <App />
    </ConnectedRouter>
  </Provider>,
  rootElement);

registerServiceWorker();
```

In app.js

```
render(){
return (
  <Layout>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
      <Route path='/login' component={Login} />
      <Route path='/logout' component={Logout} />
    </Switch>
  </Layout>
)
}
```

In NavMenu.js:

```
this.props.history.push("/login")
...
export default connect(
state => state,
dispatch => bindActionCreators(actionCreators, dispatch)
)(withRouter(/*withStyles(styles)(*/NavMenu/*)*/));
```

I put some log in rendering of Home page, and just after the first click on back button, the rendering of Home page is not called (no log).

Some ideas ? Thanks for your help !

Comment: What the Layout does? Maybe try BrowserRouter or HashRouter instad.

Comment: Layout is just rendering children with on top the navbar. You're right with BrowserRouter (remplacing ConnectedRouter by this) the problem disappears. Thanks !